# Set coredns cluster IP as resolve.conf

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

The nameserver in my pods' `resolve.conf` is not my coredns cluster IP. So it gives errors. How can I fix that?
Basically where is `--cluster-dns` flag set?

Comment: How is your cluster setup (kubeadm, minikube, ...)?

Comment: kubeunetes cluster

Comment: you should be able to find clusterDNS in /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

`--cluster-dns` is a kubelet flag. Kubelet is running as a daemon on each of your nodes. However, this flag is depracted <sup>[[source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/#:%7E:text=for%20name%20resolution.-,(DEPRECATED%3A%20This%20parameter%20should%20be%20set%20via%20the%20config%20file%20specified%20by%20the%20Kubelet%27s%20--config%20flag.%20See%20https%3A//kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/%20for%20more%20information.),---cluster-domain%20string)]</sup>, and this parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's `--config` flag.
Quick check on a node created with GKE shows that config file for kubelet is

```text
--config /home/kubernetes/kubelet-config.yaml
```

---

This file may be in different location in your case.

Easiest way to check which file is loaded as a config is to check the status of `kubelet` service

```text
systemctl status kubelet | grep "\-\-config"
```

<sup>*replace `systemctl` with your distribution's equivalent*</sup>

`--config` flag will be in bold and/or color in the output. The path after this flag (*/home/kubernetes/kubelet-config.yaml* in my case) is the file you need to edit.

---

Now, looking at that file

```text
# cat /home/kubernetes/kubelet-config.yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: /etc/srv/kubernetes/pki/ca-certificates.crt
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
cgroupRoot: /
clusterDNS: # here is the flag you are looking for
- 10.8.0.10
clusterDomain: cluster.local
enableDebuggingHandlers: true
evictionHard:
  memory.available: 100Mi
  nodefs.available: 10%
  nodefs.inodesFree: 5%
  pid.available: 10%
featureGates:
  DynamicKubeletConfig: false
  ExecProbeTimeout: false
  InTreePluginAWSUnregister: true
  InTreePluginAzureDiskUnregister: true
  InTreePluginOpenStackUnregister: true
  InTreePluginvSphereUnregister: true
  RotateKubeletServerCertificate: true
kernelMemcgNotification: true
kind: KubeletConfiguration
kubeReserved:
  cpu: 80m
  ephemeral-storage: 41Gi
  memory: 2623Mi
readOnlyPort: 10255
serverTLSBootstrap: true
staticPodPath: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
```

`clusterDNS` is specified on line 12.
Change this value and restart kubelet.

Comment: @p10l I can't find this file in worker node. /home/kubernetes/kubelet-config.yaml

Comment: Updated my answer with instructions on how to find loaded config file.